# Text2Vec classification with caret SVM warning message

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, text2vec

I am working on a text classification problem with the `text2vec` package and `caret`. I am using `text2vec` to build a document-term matrix before building different models with `caret`. The goal is to identify string similarity between two strings, using labeled training data.

However, when training a linear SVM model, I get a number of warning messages, excerpt below:

> Warning messages: 1: In svm.default(x = as.matrix(x), y = y, kernel = "linear",  ... :
>   Variable(s) ‘influenza’ and
>   ‘perindoprilindapamide’ and ‘bisoprololhct.1’ and ‘creon.1’ and ‘kreon.1’ and ‘paratramadol.1’ constant. Cannot scale data.

Can you please help me to understand these warnings and how to address **Cannot scale data**?

An excerpt of the original Training Data:

```
ID          MAKTX_Keyword       PH_Level_04_Keyword   Result 
266325638   AMLODIPINE          AMLODIPINE              0 
724712821   IRBESARTANHCTZ      IRBESARTANHCTZ          0 
567428641   RABEPRAZOLE         RABEPRAZOLE             0 
137472217   MIRTAZAPINE         MIRTAZAPINE             0 
175827784   FONDAPARINUX        ARIXTRA                 1 
456372747   VANCOMYCIN          VANCOMYCIN              0 
653832438   BRUFEN              IBUPROFEN               1 
917575539   POTASSIUM           POTASSIUM               0     
222949123   DIOSMINHESPERIDIN   DIOSMINHESPERIDIN       0 
892725684   IBUPROFEN           IBUPROFEN               0
```

Code to build SVM Model:

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3, savePredictions=TRUE, classProbs=TRUE)

Train_PRDHA_String.df$Result <- ifelse(Train_PRDHA_String.df$Result == 1, "X", "Y")

(warn=1)
(warnings=2)

t1 = Sys.time()
svm_Linear <- train(x = as.matrix(dtm_train), y = as.factor(Train_PRDHA_String.df$Result),
                    method = "svmLinear2",
                    trControl=control,
                    tuneLength = 5,
                    metric ="Accuracy")
print(difftime(Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, when these variables are resampled, they only have one unique value. You can use `preProc = "zv"` to get rid of the warning.